# Get R object value from memory address

Tags: r, memory

In R, I can get the memory address of any object by the function 'address'.

Can I do the inverse, and get an object's value from its memory address?

Comment: Within R? No. You'd probably have to write some C code. But just given an address, you have no idea how data is being stored in that chunk of memory. But what are you really trying to do where you think this would be a good idea? Is this for debugging or something?

Comment: It's a follow-on from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46346866/r-memory-blowup-when-predicting-nnet-output-in-parallel-with-foreach, with the idea being I could pass the address of the neural net rather than the net itself (thus preventing memory blowup).